# create csv file from list of tuples

Tags: python, csv

I have a list which have tuples like below:

```
lst=[(-5436.1083984375, -284.45037841796875, -13.281749725341797, 33.0), (-5436.7861328125, -275.71826171875, -15.141064643859863, 33.0), (-5302.18408203125, -197.27424621582031, -0.92733770608901978, 34.0),.....]
```

How do i write it into a csv file such that each tuple is a row in a file.

Comment: `csvobject.writerows(lst)`

Comment: why do i get this error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' `

Comment: python 3: don't write using `wb` use `"w",newline="` when opening the file for writing.

Comment: seems to work now